# Query to return rows in date range but return only max value of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to do is select the price from a table where the date given is between the start and finish date in a table.

```
SELECT price 
FROM table 
WHERE 'dategiven' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

This is easy enough with a datetime filter. Problem is I have multiple records in the time window provided, I have a version column as well.

I have below an example of my table:

[image]

I want my query output to be as below where my `dategiven` is `2013-08-25`
[image]

Milk has 3 records, 2 of them are valid for `dategiven` (2013-08-25). I then want to return the result with the highest version?

something like:

```
SELECT
    price 
FROM table 
WHERE 'dategiven' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND max(version)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `row_number()` function to rank the rows

```
select product, price, version
from
(    
    select 
        *, 
        row_number() over (partition by product order by version desc) rn
    from yourtable
    where @dategiven between startdate and enddate
) v
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be the most efficient way but:

```
select price 
 from table 
where 
  'dategiven' between startdate and enddate 
  and version = 
    (
       select max(version) from table t2 where t2.product = table.product
       and 'dategiven' between startdate and enddate 
    )
```

Comment: The date filter should be inside the subquery.

Comment: if version number are unique per product you dont need to have 'dategiven' between startdate and enddate on the main query, just putting that in the subquery should be enough

Comment: yes but it may help the optimizer do subselect on less initial rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
select t.product, t.price, version
 from table  t
 inner join
 (select product, max(version) maxVerion from table where
 'dategiven' between startdate and enddate group by product) temp
 on temp.product = t.product and t.version = temp.maxVerion
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

my computer installed is not sqlservert but mysql. I do not know it is complex.

```
  select t.product, t.price, v.version 
  (
     select temp.product, max(temp.version) as version
     from 
     (
        select product, price, startDate, endDate, version 
        from Table
        where 'dategiven' between startDate and endDate
     ) as temp
     group by temp.product
  ) as v
  inner join Table as t
  on v.version = t.version
```